# Speeding up the porting of an iPad application to Android

Tags: android, ios, porting

My work consists of porting an iPad application to Android (so from Objective-C to Java). I've developed in the Android environment, but never in iOS. Currently I am looking for advice -- I'd like to know if is there a way, method, or process which can help me to do this more easily.

Answer (score 3):

At this stage generally the answer is no, but I've got some suggestions that might help.

- Use UIWebView/Webkit extensively - baring any HTML5 media (and SVG), there's little porting required when you render HTML. What you render in one, generally, renders well on the other.
- If your iOS app is a basic show-this-edit-that style of app, you may find PhoneGap, jQuery Mobile, Titanium or the new Adobe suite a better time investment.
- Because Android lacks a consistent device base, which makes developing animation-rich UIs difficult, you might find that there is no 1-1 UI comparison. Instead think about the features you offer, and their underlying data and view models.
- You should be able to create a similar UIViewController/Activities structure although the tying logic behind the scenes will be platform specific. Map this out on some paper - it makes a really good what-the-hell-do-i-do-next plan for your UI skeleton.
- Prefer an intermediate abstraction between your 'in data' and 'out data' so you can exchange parsers/kits/apis/frameworks without hacking everything to bits.
- Where you have custom draw routines and graphics, ensure that you've got filler gradients or colours. Android uses a box model to support the many many screen sizes - iOS only has 4 resolutions to worry about. Recreating the same look might take too much time - [contrasting pastel colours](http://kuler.adobe.com/) are a good placeholder until you can justify making the artwork.

There's not a lot more that can say [that hasn't already been said before](http://nfarina.com/post/8239634061/ios-to-android).

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Few advices:

- You will in most cases need to do redesign of UI as iPad, being tablet PC and having a larger screen as compared with most Android devices.  Advice: Check if there is a version of the application dedicated for iPhone as it could be very helpful during redesign stage.
- Check if iPad code contains beside Objective-C code also C/C++ code. If there is significant amount of code you might consider using Android NDK which allows C/C++ code to be used together with Java.
- If the iPad application was using one of the popular cross platform frameworks (e.g. PhoneGap) that are based on HTML5/CSS/JavaScript combination you might be able to reuse most of the code. Both iPad and Android browser/ui elements responsible for rendering HTML5 are based on same engine (WebKit) and generally generate similar experience. Note: Some frameworks allow custom access to native functionalities which will require rewrite in almost all cases.
- Do not try to create exact same UI on Android if it conflicts with user interface guidelines. As you probably know the guidelines are available at: http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/ui_guidelines/index.html
  Android users are used to certain interface and they should be getting similar experience as other apps available for Android. Also it might be more than painful to create similar controls for Android that exist on iPad. If there is pressure to make same "look and feel" here is a post that explains how to defend from such pressures: [Porting iPhone applications to Android? How to convince them NOT to](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6358069/porting-iphone-applications-to-android-how-to-convince-them-not-to)
- Numerous features existing on iPad will not be available on Android (e.g. Android application splash screen using just an image). So analyse the iPad application and decompose it to set of functionalities.  Once you have them then you can map them to Android API and start coding.
- There are no Objective-C to Java converters at the moment (this might change in the future) but for general feeling what are differences between Objective-C and Java you might want to read "Porting Objective-C to Java" by Theresa Ray of Tensor Information Systems Inc